# How do I insert into or update a table with data from multiple other tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a few tables:

table1:

| USER_NAME | USER_NUM |
| --- | --- |
| Billy Bob | Q1 |
| Billy Joe | Q2 |
| John Doe | Q3 |

table2:

| USER_NUM | USER_ID |
| --- | --- |
| Q1 | 1 |
| Q2 | 2 |
| Q3 | 3 |

table3:

| USER_ID | MATERIAL_NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | M1 |
| 1 | M2 |
| 2 | M1 |
| 2 | M3 |
| 3 | M3 |

table4:

| MATERIAL_ID | MATERIAL_NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | M1 |
| 112 | M2 |
| 113 | M3 |

And this is how I want table5 to look:

| OWNER_ID | MATERIAL_ID | USER_NUM | USER_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | 111 | Q1 | Billy Bob |
| 223 | 111 | Q2 | Billy Joe |
| 224 | 112 | Q1 | Billy Bob |
| 225 | 113 | Q2 | Billy Joe |
| 226 | 113 | Q3 | John Doe |

The table already has `OWNER_ID` and `MATERIAL_ID` filled in so I just need `USER_NUM` and `USER_NAME` unless it would be easier to repopulate it from scratch.

This is the query I have tried but it's not working at all (I'm getting row is ambiguously defined error):

```
UPDATE table5 t5
   SET t5.USER_NUM = (SELECT UPPER(t1.USER_NUM)
                        FROM table1 t1
                       INNER JOIN table2 t2
                          ON t1.USER_NUM = t2.USER_NUM
                       INNER JOIN table3 t3
                          ON t2.USER_ID = t3.USER_ID
                       INNER JOIN table4 t4
                          ON t3.MATERIAL_NUM = t4.MATERIAL_NUM
                       WHERE t4.MATERIAL_ID = t5.MATERIAL_ID);
```

The query to update the table with `USER_NAME` should be easy once I get the `USER_NUM` in there but if someone knows how to do both at once that would be nice as well =)

Comment: Do you know about normalization and intentionally want a denormalized table? If not, you should do some research about normalization and realize that having those columns in the 5th table is a bad thing in general. If yes, then you should think twice if denormalization is really that helpful for you that it's worth the risks coming with it. You may also [edit] your question and elaborate on the actual problem to get further advice on that subject.

Comment: I'm trying to consolidate the data I want to 1 table so that it's easy to work with. I'm not familiar with normalization. Whoever set up my database built the tables without primary/ foreign keys or unique values. I'm an intern/ college student who's only been working with SQL for 3 months. I don't have any other developers around to ask for help and I was just handed someone else's project. They were gone before I got here so I can't even ask them why they did what they did.

Comment: OK, then as I said, study on the subject of normalization. "easy to work with" is not a particularly good reason for denormalization. You can create a view with the respective joins for convenience but you should not materialize that in a table.

Comment: I'm trying to redesign the tables so that they are organized and make sense with the goal of the app I'm trying to develop.

Comment: I'll look into normalization.

Comment: I mean at a glance the point of normalization is to reduce redundancy of information. The goal of this table is to not need the others/ eliminate them. By consolidating the information to this table, wouldn't that normalize the data by reducing repetition?

Comment: I want table5 to be in first normal form and become the table that others are expanded from.

Comment: It **introduces** redundancy. E.g the user name is stored in two tables. If the name changes it has to be changed in both tables. If one of the tables is forgotten to change, you got inconsistent data. (Which of the user names is the right one?)

Comment: The data in table1 is not going to be updated after the transfer is complete. Once it is used to populate table5, table1 can be discarded. Then the only user name that matters is in table5 correct?

Comment: Since there are no relations between owner_id and first four tables there is no way to map user_num and user_name with material_id since there are two rows for each_material_id. Please explain the situation.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur I am using owner_ID as the primary key for the table to give each row a unique value. It was my solution for being able to add multiple users to a single material.

Comment: If it's just a sequential number then I would suggest to create table5 from those four tables instead of updating it.

Comment: Just create a view with the query that generates the table you want.  There is no need to store the data in a separate table.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur can you write your idea as an answer for what you recommend?

Comment: @GordonLinoff If I create a view, will I be able to reference the view for my app the same way I could a table?

Comment: @TheSchmidly: There's also redundancy in the final table you envision. There are more than one rows with the same user name. If you update just some rows but miss some there's inconsistency as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of updating table5 I am suggesting to insert data into it. I have created a sequence named table5_seq then selected it as `OWNER_ID`.

```
 create table table1(USER_NAME varchar(50), USER_NUM varchar(50));

 insert into table1 values('Billy Bob', 'Q1');
 insert into table1 values('Billy Joe', 'Q2');
 insert into table1 values('John Doe',  'Q3');

 create table table2(USER_NUM varchar(50),  USER_ID int);
 insert into table2 values('Q1',    1); 
 insert into table2 values('Q2',    2);
 insert into table2 values('Q3',    3);
 
 create table table3 (USER_ID int, MATERIAL_NUMBER varchar(50));
 insert into table3 values(1    ,'M1');
 insert into table3 values(1    ,'M2'); 
 insert into table3 values(2    ,'M1'); 
 insert into table3 values(2    ,'M3'); 
 insert into table3 values(3    ,'M3');
  
 create table table4 (MATERIAL_ID int,  MATERIAL_NUMBER varchar(50));
 insert into table4 values(111  ,'M1'); 
 insert into table4 values(112  ,'M2');
 insert into table4 values(113  ,'M3');

 create table table5(OWNER_ID int,  MATERIAL_ID varchar(50),    USER_NUM varchar(50),   USER_NAME varchar(50));     

 CREATE SEQUENCE table5_seq
  START WITH     1
  INCREMENT BY   1
  NOCACHE
  NOCYCLE;
```

Insert query:

```
 insert into table5
 SELECT table5_seq.NextVal,t4.MATERIAL_NUMBER, UPPER(t1.USER_NUM) USER_NUM,UPPER(t1.USER_NAME)USER_NAME
     FROM table1 t1
     INNER JOIN table2 t2
         ON t1.USER_NUM = t2.USER_NUM
     INNER JOIN table3 t3
         ON t2.USER_ID = t3.USER_ID
     INNER JOIN table4 t4
         ON t3.MATERIAL_NUMBER = t4.MATERIAL_NUMBER;
```

Output:

| OWNER_ID | MATERIAL_ID | USER_NUM | USER_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M1 | Q1 | BILLY BOB |
| 2 | M1 | Q2 | BILLY JOE |
| 3 | M2 | Q1 | BILLY BOB |
| 4 | M3 | Q2 | BILLY JOE |
| 5 | M3 | Q3 | JOHN DOE |

Or as Gordon suggested you can create a view also:

```
 create view view_table5 
 as
     SELECT t4.MATERIAL_NUMBER, UPPER(t1.USER_NUM) USER_NUM,UPPER(t1.USER_NAME)USER_NAME
     FROM table1 t1
     INNER JOIN table2 t2
         ON t1.USER_NUM = t2.USER_NUM
     INNER JOIN table3 t3
         ON t2.USER_ID = t3.USER_ID
     INNER JOIN table4 t4
         ON t3.MATERIAL_NUMBER = t4.MATERIAL_NUMBER;


 select * from view_table5;
```

Output:

| MATERIAL_NUMBER | USER_NUM | USER_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M1 | Q1 | BILLY BOB |
| M1 | Q2 | BILLY JOE |
| M2 | Q1 | BILLY BOB |
| M3 | Q2 | BILLY JOE |
| M3 | Q3 | JOHN DOE |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e611aff08216a934d7097baaafe303c1)*